# Global declaration and usage array of objects C#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio, global

> ; Expected at(near "}" )  proc = { new Process(i, bts[i], 1) };

I don't know how to fix it. I think its some kind of syntax problem

```
//code starts  
Process[] proc = new Process[3];

public void prentry()
{
    int[] bts = new int[999];
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        string txtid = "TextBox" + i;
        // MessageBox.Show();
        bts[i] = Convert.ToInt32(((TextBox)(this.Controls[(txtid)])).Text);
        proc = { new Process(i, bts[i], 1) }; //problem here                
    }
    GFG.findavgTime(proc, proc.Length);
```

Comment: The syntax `= { ... }` is only allowed when you declare the array. If you want to reassign the array variable later, you have to use one of the two following forms: `= new[] { ... }` (only if the type is discernible by the contents of the array initializer), or `= new Process[] { ... }`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `proc` is an array, do you want to assign to one of its elements or replace the entire array?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem when learning this new syntax for initializing arrays. One could easily mistake the following two to do the same thing and both work:

```
int[] a = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

and

```
int[] a;
a = { 1, 2, 3 };
```

but sadly that is not so. The `= { elements }` syntax is only allowed when you declare the variable.

Instead you have two alternatives, and here I'll switch to your example:

```
proc = new[] { ... elements ... };
proc = new Process[] { ... elements ... };
```

You can drop the `Process` part if the compiler is able to understand that you're creating an array of `Process` objects, which it can in your case.

---

Now, having said all of that, that only explains the compiler error.

My *guess* is that you don't want it to behave like this. You've declared and initialized the `proc` array to have 999 elements, you *probably* don't want to reassign *the whole array* on each iteration through your loop.

Basically, I think you want this:

```
proc[i] = new Process(i, bts[i], 1);
```

(or some variation of this). This would assign the new `Process` object to one of the existing elements of the 999-element array.

Answer (score 1):

The following will probably work

```
proc = new [] {new Process(i, bts[i], 1)} ;
```

[Single-Dimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays)

Comment: But `proc` is an array